# Core Data with Array Attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

The following is the entity `Player` header file.

```
@interface Player : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * experience;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id items;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * level;

@end

@interface items : NSValueTransformer
@end
```

`items` is essentially an `NSMutableArray` with `NSNumber` elements. And inside one function, I'm updating this array:

```
- (void)itemWasDropped:(ItemIndex)item
{ // _player has been correctly retrieved from the database
    // the current number of this item
    int nNum = [[_player.items objectAtIndex:item] intValue];
    // to increment the number
    [_player.items replaceObjectAtIndex:item withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nNum + 1]];
}
```

This function gets called perfectly. I save the context in the `viewWillDisappear` function.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{ // _moc is an NSManagedObjectContext instance that has been correctly initialised.
    // to update the database
    NSError* err = nil;
    BOOL bSucc = [_moc save:&err];
    if (err || !bSucc)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the updates are visible in other views as long as I do not shut down the app in the task bar. What's the problem? Anyone can help?

Comment: is each view using its own Managed Object Context?

Comment: No, the context is the same. Every view asks the AppDelegate for the context. If the context hasn't been initialised, it's initialised and returned. If it has, the AppDelegate simply returns it.

Comment: Just solved it. In order to update an array attribute inside a Core Data entity, that array has to be assigned to another `@property` array in the view controller class or whatever, and update the `@property` array. Before database updating, the `@property` array has to be assigned back to the entity attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core data can store arrays, but you will have to use a "transformable" attribute. In general it is not very good design. One easy solution is to transform your numbers array into something that can be stored. For example, in many cases it is sufficient to just use a string.

Encode:

```
player.items = [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@","];
// Swift
player.items = numbers.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

Decode:

```
NSMutableArray* numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *s in [player.items componentsSeparatedByString:@","]) {
  [numbers addObject:@([s integerValue])];
}
// Swift
let numbers = player.items.characters.split { $0 == "," } .map { Int($0!) }
```

Comment: Thanks but Core Data can do it by Transformable. I've tried this and it works.

Comment: Just solved it. In order to update an array attribute inside a Core Data entity, that array has to be assigned to another `@property` array in the view controller class or whatever, and update the `@property` array. Before database updating, the `@property` array has to be assigned back to the entity attribute.

Comment: If you've solved it, you should post your answer in detail so that others can read and understand your solution. 

Also, why didn't you use a one-to-many relationship with a different entity type?

Comment: The website said I can't answer my own questions within some tens of hours.Because the array has a predefined length and stores only predefined values, I didn't bother to make up a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it. In order to update an array attribute inside a Core Data entity, that array has to be assigned to another `@property` array in the view controller class or, and update the `@property` array. Before database updating, the `@property` array has to be assigned back to the entity attribute.

```
// to hold the player items
// _player.items cannot be directly updated
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* items;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSMutableArray* results = [[_moc executeFetchRequest:fr error:&err] mutableCopy];
    if (err || results.count == 0)
    {
        ...
    } else
    {
        _player = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        _items = _player.items;
    }
}

// events
- (void)itemWasDropped:(ItemIndex)item
{
    // the current number of this item
    int nNum = [[_items objectAtIndex:item] intValue];
    // to increment the number
    [_items replaceObjectAtIndex:item withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nNum + 1]];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // to update the database
    _player.items = _items;
    NSError* err = nil;
    BOOL bSucc = [_moc save:&err];
    if (err || !bSucc)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```